# Converting a DOCX to a DOC in Ruby

Tags: ruby, docx, doc, file-conversion

How do I convert a DOCX file to a DOC using Ruby?

Comment: You'd probably have Rails invoke a system command for this, since I doubt there are any Ruby- or Rails-specific gems here. Consider broadening your search.

Comment: You know, what Rails is, and what Rails for, right? WHY did you use this tag here?!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at unoconv. It does all the conversion supported by OpenOffice from the command line

http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/

Comment: Thanks for this. I took a look but it doesn't have docx on it

Comment: According to the website it does not support docx as export. However it seems to support docx as import (see: http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Framework/Article/Filter/FilterList_OOo_3_0) Since you're looking for docx to doc it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

DOCX support from OpenOffice and Libre Office is still pretty weak.  There is a free 3rd party lib (odfconverter) that is much better at formatting.  If you can link this in with your app or do some preprocessing that would be a likely good result.  Note that new versions of MS Office read ODT format fairly well so that may provide another avenue for you to investigate.
So, odfconverter would give you docx->odt.  Docmosis or JODReports could do the odt->doc.